# Use common table name across inheritance in ef core

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0, tablename

I am new to entity framework and started playing around with it. I am trying to use my usual structure that consists of a `Core` project that has raw properties. `DataAccess` extends core classes and adds any additional db specific property and the `DBContext` in this case. `Business` extends `DataAccess` and has all business logic. Finally, a `Models` project where multiple models may extend each business class for different purposes.

My class in `Core` is something like this:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

My `DataAcceess` got a context class like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

And my `Business` got this:

```
public class Blog : DataAccess.Blog
{
    public void Add()
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            db.Blogs.Add(this);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally my `Models` contains:

```
public class BlogModel : Business.Blog {}
```

Now I get an error that the entity type `BlogModel` doesn't exist. The table's name is Blog not BlogModel. I have tried the following:

1. Adding `[Table("Blog")]` in DataAccess, Business and Model
2. casting this as `(Blog)this`. The type still stays the same
3. Creating a property `Blog Current => this` trying to change it's type.

**Update:** happens even when the model is named `Blog`

Comment: Well, I can't say of that's "by design" or is a current implementation bug/limitation, but all EF Core methods receiving entity instances ('Add`, `Attach`, `Remove`, `Update` etc.) uses `entity.GetType()` method and requires the returned type to be a "entity type". Hence passing derived type intances as in your case won't work.

Comment: well as mentioned in this bug report, apparently it isn't a bug
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8728

Comment: but isn't this exactly what `[Table()]` is meant for?

Comment: That's different subject. In your case, the only "entity" class is `Blog` from `DbSet<Blog>`. See [Including & Excluding Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-types).

Comment: yeah, after testing what i have mentioned in the update, i realized how DbSet actually works

Comment: thanks for the link. however it doesn't look like it an help my case without creating circular references. do you know of any git samples that use ef core with business logic?